# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 using Vector

Tags: java, vector, indexoutofboundsexception

I am getting an error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at tesseract.BlockMaze.generate(BlockMaze.java:128)
    at tesseract.MazeMap.<init>(MazeMap.java:17)
    at tesseract.main.init(main.java:29)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here are the parts:

main line 29:

```
    map = new MazeMap(mwidth, mheight);
```

MazeMap line 17:

```
    generate(false);
```

BlockMaze line 128:

```
    maze[startX = 0][startY = rint(mzHyt - 2) + 1] = FLOOR;
```

I am using a Vector type and I was wondering if maybe that was the problem that I was having.  Is Vector a deprecated type and is there a replacement.  Also is there an alternative, because I tried using ArrayList, but I wasn't entirely sure if it would do the same exact thing.

Here is BlockMaze:

```
package tesseract;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Vector;

public class BlockMaze extends Maze{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -4392133669361871887L;
public static final byte WALL = 0, FLOOR = 1;
private Vector  pending;     // list of available Sqr objects
private int     strt =  70;  // prob of exploring from same sqr
private int     sdir =  60;  // prob of exploring in same dir (if possible)
private int     thru =  90;  // prob of blocking thru loops
private int     side =  60;  // prob of blocking wide areas
private int     diag = 100;  // prob of blocking diag connections
private int     dens =  15;  // prob of leaving areas unexplored

public BlockMaze () {
    setBackground(Color.black);
}

protected byte initSq () { return (byte) (WALL | DIRTY); }

protected void drawSquare (int xx, int yy) {
    offscr.setColor(maze[xx][yy] == WALL ? Color.gray : Color.white);
    offscr.fillRect(leftOffset + (xx * sqWid), topOffset + (yy * sqHyt), sqWid, sqHyt);
}

public boolean isOpen (int x, int y) {
    return inBounds(x, y)  &&  sqr(x, y) == FLOOR;
}

private boolean isOpen (int x, int y, int allowProb) {
    return prob(allowProb)  &&  isOpen(x, y);
}

private boolean blocked (int x, int y) {
    return inBounds(x, y)  &&  sqr(x, y) == WALL;
}

private boolean noDiag (int x, int y, int dx, int dy) {
    return blocked(x + dx, y)  &&  blocked(x, y + dy)  &&  isOpen(x + dx, y + dy, diag);
}

private boolean tryDir (int x, int y, int dir) {
    // Step #7 - check if the adjacent square in direction 'dir' should be
added to the maze
    // Currently I disallow any move that would create a loop or a path width
    // greater than one square.  However, I believe I can get more interesting
    // mazes if I use probability to selectively allow this.
    switch (dir) {
        case TOP:
            y--;
            if (isOpen(x, y - 1, thru) ||
                    isOpen(x - 1, y, side) || isOpen(x + 1, y, side) ||
                    noDiag(x, y, -1, -1) || noDiag(x, y, 1, -1))
                return false;
            break;
        case BOTTOM:
            y++;
            if (isOpen(x, y + 1, thru) ||
                    isOpen(x - 1, y, side) || isOpen(x + 1, y, side) ||
                    noDiag(x, y, -1, 1) || noDiag(x, y, 1, 1))
                return false;
            break;
        case LEFT:
            x--;
            if (isOpen(x - 1, y, thru) ||
                    isOpen(x, y - 1, side) || isOpen(x, y + 1, side) ||
                    noDiag(x, y, -1, -1) || noDiag(x, y, -1, 1))
                return false;
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            x++;
            if (isOpen(x + 1, y, thru) ||
                    isOpen(x, y - 1, side) || isOpen(x, y + 1, side) ||
                    noDiag(x, y, 1, -1) || noDiag(x, y, 1, 1))
                return false;
            break;
    }
    if (finishX < 0  &&  x == mzWid - 1) {
        finishX = x;  finishY = y;  // found exit
    }
    else if (x <= 0  ||  x >= mzWid - 1  ||  y <= 0  ||  y >= mzHyt - 1)
        return false;  // square on border or out of bounds
    else {
        Sqr sq = new Sqr(x, y, dir, blocked(x, y-1), blocked(x, y+1),
                                    blocked(x-1, y), blocked(x+1, y));
        // if pruning density, replace last pending Sqr
        if (pending.size() > 10  &&  prob(dens))
            pending.setElementAt(sq, pending.size() - 1);
        else  // not pruning, add pending Sqr to list
            pending.addElement(sq);
    }
    maze[x][y] = FLOOR;
    dirtySquare(x, y);
    return true;
}

/* Here are the steps generate() uses to generate a maze:
 *  1.  Set all the squares in the maze grid to WALL.
 *  2.  Randomly select a non-corner square on the left edge of the maze,
 *      set the square to FLOOR. Create a Sqr object with the RIGHT direction
 *      unexplored and add it to the list of available squares.
 *  3.  If the list of available squares is empty, then you're done.
 *  4.  Select a square to explore from the list of available squares.
 *  5.  If less than two directions remain to be explored from the square,
 *      remove the square from the list of available squares. You remove
 *      the square from the list because no directions will be left to
 *      explore after you process the square.
 *  6.  Select a direction to explore from the square and mark the direction
 *      as explored.
 *  7.  Check to see if you should add the square in the selected direction
 *      to the maze grid. If the answer is ÔyesÕ, then add the square to the
 *      maze and to the list of available squares.
 *  8.  Goto step 3.
 */

public synchronized void generate (boolean displayConstruction) {
    int free, idx;

    // Step #1 - initialize the maze
    clearMaze();
    if (displayConstruction)
        showMaze(true);

    // Step #2 - select and set the starting square
    pending = new Vector();
    maze[startX = 0][startY = rint(mzHyt - 2) + 1] = FLOOR;
    dirtySquare(startX, startY);
    pending.addElement(new Sqr(startX, startY, RIGHT, false, false, false, true));

    // Step #3 - loop until list of squares is empty
    while (!pending.isEmpty()) {
        // Step #4 - select a square to explore
        // You can vary the "character" of the generated maze by adjusting how
frequently
        // the algorithm chooses to continue expanding from the current square vs. how
        // frequently it randomly picks another queue square.
        if (prob(strt))
            idx = pending.size() - 1;
        else
            idx = rint(pending.size());
        Sqr next = (Sqr) pending.elementAt(idx);
        // Step #5 - remove the square if this is the last side to explore
        // Also randomly remove squares to reduce maze density.
        if ((free = next.open()) <= 1  ||  (pending.size() > 10  &&  prob(dens)))
            pending.removeElementAt(idx);
        if (free > 0) {
            // Step #6a - select a direction to explore
            // You can also vary the character of the maze by altering the probability
that
            // Sqr.select() will be asked to try to continue to expand the next square
in the
            // same direction we entered the square being expanded.  This tends to
reduce
            // the zig-zag nature that results from straight random
selection of direction.
            if (tryDir(next.x, next.y, next.select(rint(free), prob(sdir))))
                if (displayConstruction)
                    showMaze(false);
        }
        // Step #8 - explore another square
    }
    if (!displayConstruction)
        repaint();
}

public synchronized boolean traverse (int sx, int sy, int fx, int fy, boolean
displaySearch) {
    if (!inBounds(sx, sy)  ||  !inBounds(fx, fy))
        return false;

    int         dir, xx = sx, yy = sy, count = 0;
    int         qhead, qtail, qsize = (mzWid + mzHyt - 1) * 2;
    short[][]   queue = new short[qsize][2];  // 0 = x, 1 = y
    byte[][]    graph = new byte[mzWid][mzHyt];
    boolean     solve = (xx == startX && yy == startY && fx == finishX && fy ==finishY);

    if (displaySearch) {
        resetPath();
        if (solve) {
            path[sx][sy] = LEFT;
            dirtySquare(sx, sy);
        }
        showMaze(false);
    }
    graph[xx][yy] = -1;
    queue[0][0] = (short)xx;  queue[0][1] = (short)yy;
    qtail = 0;  qhead = 1;

 TRAVERSE:
    for (;;) {
        if (qhead == qtail) {  // queue is empty: unsolvable maze
            resetPath();
            if (displayPath)
                repaint();
            return false;
        }
        xx = queue[qtail][0];  yy = queue[qtail][1];
        qtail = (qtail + 1) % qsize;
        int qstart = qhead;
        for (dir = TOP;  dir <= LEFT;  dir <<= 1) {
            int ndir = 0, nx = xx, ny = yy;
            switch (dir) {
                case TOP:     ny--;  ndir = BOTTOM;  break;
                case RIGHT:   nx++;  ndir = LEFT;    break;
                case BOTTOM:  ny++;  ndir = TOP;     break;
                case LEFT:    nx--;  ndir = RIGHT;   break;
            }
            if (inBounds(nx, ny)  &&  graph[nx][ny] == 0  &&  sqr(nx, ny) == FLOOR) {
                // extend the search path in direction <dir>
                graph[nx][ny] = (byte)ndir;  // point to previous square
                if (displaySearch) {
                    path[xx][yy] |= dir;
                    dirtySquare(xx, yy);
                    path[nx][ny] |= ndir;
                    dirtySquare(nx, ny);
                }
                if (nx == fx  &&  ny == fy)  // found solution
                    break TRAVERSE;
                queue[qhead][0] = (short)nx;  queue[qhead][1] = (short)ny;
                qhead = (qhead + 1) % qsize;
            }
        }
        if (displaySearch) {
            if (qhead == qstart) {  // dead end, backtrack
                while (path[xx][yy] == graph[xx][yy]) {
                    path[xx][yy] = 0;
                    dirtySquare(xx, yy);
                    switch (graph[xx][yy]) {
                        case TOP:     path[xx][--yy] &= (byte)~BOTTOM;  break;
                        case RIGHT:   path[++xx][yy] &= (byte)~LEFT;    break;
                        case BOTTOM:  path[xx][++yy] &= (byte)~TOP;     break;
                        case LEFT:    path[--xx][yy] &= (byte)~RIGHT;   break;
                    }
                    dirtySquare(xx, yy);
                }
            }
            showMaze(false);
        }
        else if ((++count & 0xFF) == 0)
            Thread.yield();
    }
    if (displaySearch) {
        if (solve) {
            path[xx][yy] |= RIGHT;
            dirtySquare(xx, yy);
        }
        showMaze(false);
    }

    // reconstruct path by following graph from finish to start
    resetPath();
    if (solve)
        path[fx][fy] = RIGHT;
    while ((dir = graph[fx][fy]) != -1) {
        path[fx][fy] |= (byte)dir;
        switch (dir) {
            case TOP:     path[fx][--fy] = BOTTOM;  break;
            case RIGHT:   path[++fx][fy] = LEFT;    break;
            case BOTTOM:  path[fx][++fy] = TOP;     break;
            case LEFT:    path[--fx][fy] = RIGHT;   break;
        }
    }
    if (solve)
        path[fx][fy] |= LEFT;
    if (displayPath)
        repaint();
    return true;
}
}  // public class BlockMaze



class Sqr {
private boolean t, b, l, r;  // top, bottom, left, right
private int     dir;         // direction square entered
int             x, y;        // coordinates of square

Sqr (int x, int y, int dir, boolean t, boolean b, boolean l, boolean r) {
    this.x = x;  this.y = y;
    this.dir = dir;
    this.t = t;  this.b = b;  this.l = l;  this.r = r;
}

// open() returns a count of the unexplored directions
int open () {
    return (t ? 1 : 0) + (b ? 1 : 0) + (r ? 1 : 0) + (l ? 1 : 0);
}

int select (int n, boolean sameDir) {
    // Step #6b - select a direction to explore and mark the direction as explored
    if (sameDir)  // try to expand in same direction the square was entered from
        switch (dir) {
            case Maze.TOP:    if (t) { t = false; return dir; }  break;
            case Maze.BOTTOM: if (b) { b = false; return dir; }  break;
            case Maze.LEFT:   if (l) { l = false; return dir; }  break;
            case Maze.RIGHT:  if (r) { r = false; return dir; }  break;
        }
    // return the 'n'th unexplored direction
    if      (t && --n < 0) { t = false; return Maze.TOP;    }
    else if (b && --n < 0) { b = false; return Maze.BOTTOM; }
    else if (r && --n < 0) { r = false; return Maze.RIGHT;  }
    else                   { l = false; return Maze.LEFT;   }
}
}  // class Sqr
```

Here is the array maze.

```
protected byte[][] maze, path;
```

And this is what reinitializes the maze:

```
protected void showMaze (boolean allDirty) {
    if (allDirty  ||  offscreenImage == null)
        repaint();
    else
        repaint(leftOffset + minXdirty * sqWid, topOffset + minYdirty * sqHyt,
                sqWid * (maxXdirty - minXdirty + 1) + lineWid,
                sqHyt * (maxYdirty - minYdirty + 1) + lineHyt);
    try { wait(); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if ((timer -= t - (1000L / maxFrameRate)) > 0)
        try { Thread.sleep(timer); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

protected void clearMaze(){
    if(maze == null)
        maze = new byte[mzWid][mzHyt];
    byte sq = initSq();
    for(int xx = mzWid; --xx >= 0;)
        for(int yy = mzHyt; --yy >= 0;)
        maze[xx][yy] = sq;
    minXdirty = minYdirty = 0;
    maxXdirty = mzWid - 1;
    maxYdirty = mzHyt - 1;
    startX = finishX = -1;
    path = null;
}
```

I believe this is what I was looking for:

```
public synchronized void setDimensions(int squaresWide, int squaresHigh){
    if(mzWid != squaresWide || mzHyt != squaresHigh){
        mzWid = Math.max(3,  squaresWide);  //min maze width is 3 squares
        mzHyt = Math.max(3,  squaresHigh);  //min maze height is 3 squares
        maze = null;
        resetMaze();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you initialize `maze`?

Comment: As far as I can see, you are not using a `Vector` (and no: I didn't look at your pastebin, you should include Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example in your question itself).

Comment: Pastebin shouldn't be used to post code on this site, as they only last a day. If the question isn't answered in time, people won't have code to refer to in the future. It's also good for historical reasons; people in the future will be able to use this to post to answer their question (rather than posting a new one). Next time, just post the code directly to here. If it's long, do what @MarkRotteveel said and size it down to only the pure necessities.

Comment: the maze array is not in the showMaze function at all.  Can you show the clearMaze() function and also list all the functions in Maze?

Comment: These are the functions:    getDimensions(), setDimensions, resetMaze(), resetPath (), reshape, showMaze, drawPathSquare, drawTarget, paintOffscreenImage,

Comment: maze = new byte[mzWid][mzHyt]; is maze being initialized.  the error shown (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0) would imply that either mzWid or mzHyt is equal to zero which would cause this error. is your maze width or height 0?  Maze might also be initialized as zero somewhere else in the code.  check other places for something like "maze = new byte[mzWid][mzHyt];"

Answer (score 1):

Vector is older, but that's not your issue - elements are numbered from 0, so if you're asking for element 0 you need to have at least 1 element in there.

Vector is not marked as deprecated, but it will be slower than ArrayList because it is synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

The "0" in the error message is the index that is out of bounds.  If you have no zero'th element then your `Vector` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Either you didn't initialize your array maze or for some reason you initialized it with a size of 0.

Comment: I don't think I have array called maze.  The IDE is giving me a yellow underline on Vector, pending.setElementAt(sq, pending.size() - 1);, pending.addElement(sq);, Vector(), and pending.addElement(new Sqr(startX, startY, RIGHT, false, false, false, true));.  For the first Vector, when I hover over it it gives me this:Vector is a raw type. References to generic type Vector<E> should be parameterized.

Comment: The Line of code that is causing the error looks to have nothing to do with your Vector.  it is filling an array called maze and the error is an arrayindexoutofboundsexception.  "maze[..][..]=FLOOR" that means an array is being filled called maze.  Figure out where that maze array is coming from.  If you are using Eclipse IDE, put the cursor on maze and hit F3.  It is probably located in your Maze class.

Comment: Looking at your code.   // Step #1 - initialize the maze  it looks like you cleared the maze using clearMaze(); but you probably need to reinitialize it somehow.  This is just a guess, I have no idea since I don't know what your Maze class looks like.  Can you post that class or the interface?